# How to get the time from a list of objects and set it to "time ago" using JodaTime and Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, jodatime

So I'm trying to add the `time ago` to `posts` in my application, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  Right now I have a `post` entity with the `LocalDateTime` saved on to it, but I'm not sure how to get the `time ago` onto the model.

Right now I have everything happening in the controller, but I'll show you guys what the `Post` entity looks like.

```
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property = "@id")
public class Post implements Comparable<Post> {
private Long id;
@Size(min = 1, max = 140)
@NotNull
private String title;
@Size(min = 1, max = 1000)
private String content;
private Course course;
private Set<Comment> comments = new TreeSet<>();
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MMM-YYYY")
private LocalDate date;
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "HH:mm:ss")
private LocalTime time;
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
private LocalDateTime dateTime;

private User user;

@Id
@GeneratedValue
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getContent() {
    return content;
}

public void setContent(String content) {
    this.content = content;
}

@ManyToOne
public Course getCourse() {
    return course;
}

public void setCourse(Course course) {
    this.course = course;
}

@ManyToOne
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public LocalDate getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(LocalDate date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public LocalTime getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(LocalTime time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public LocalDateTime getDateTime() {
    return dateTime;
}

public void setDateTime(LocalDateTime dateTime) {
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
}

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "post")
public Set<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(Set<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Post other = (Post) obj;
    if (id == null) {
        if (other.id != null)
            return false;
    } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
        return false;
    return true;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Post o) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return getId().compareTo(o.getId());
}

}
```

Here's my Controller Method, and this currently doesn't work, but I have no idea how to go about getting the time from each post that I get from each course and then using the JodaTime library to show up as `time ago`

```
@RequestMapping(value="{user}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String userPageGet (ModelMap model, @AuthenticationPrincipal User user)
{
    List<StudySet> studySets = studySetRepo.findByUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("studySets", studySets);

    List<Course> courses = courseRepo.findByUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("courses", courses);

    Set<Post> posts = new TreeSet<>();

    for (Course course : courses) {
        posts.addAll(course.getPosts());
    }

    List<Post> postList = new ArrayList<>(posts);
    Collections.reverse(postList);

    model.addAttribute("posts", postList);


    Period period = new Period( , now); //This doesn't work

    PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
            .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds ago\n")
            .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes ago\n")
            .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hours ago\n")
            .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days ago\n")
            .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" weeks ago\n")
            .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months ago\n")
            .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years ago\n")
            .printZeroNever()
            .toFormatter();

    String elapsed = formatter.print(period);
    model.addAttribute("elapsed", elapsed);


    return "user";
}
```

So overall all I'm trying to do is get the time from the post and turn it into `time ago` to show on the model.  But specifically my idea is to get the time from each `post` in the `postList` and then use that and compare it to the `now` in the `new period` line and then display it on the model as `elapsed`.  My main problem is getting the time from each post in the `postList`

If anyone can see a solution to my problem, or point me in the right direction, that would be great, thanks in advance.

Comment: You first need to determine what is the largest unit with non-zero-amount before you are going to print the period. Joda-Time is not very good in supporting you doing this (there are better libraries around for relative times). I think there is no other way than to manually calculate if a period is bigger than one year, one month and so on (lot of awkward if-else-branches). Also, what about singular form (if amount is 1)?

Comment: Ok, what's a better library for relative time? I'm open to trying others.

Answer (score 2):

First observation about the **annotations used in your entity**:

I suspect that the mapping of `LocalDateTime` should rather be towards `java.sql.Timestamp` using the JPA-annotation `TemporalType.TIMESTAMP` otherwise the time part will get lost.

**Your period formatting** looks like as if you

- are satisfied with English only
- intend to use it for debugging and not for representation to end users

Then following Joda-solution will probably be enough:

```
// you can use in production: LocalDateTime ldt = post.getDateTime();
LocalDateTime ldt = new LocalDateTime(2013, 4, 11, 17, 45); // for test purpose 
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(); // uses your system timezone
Period p = new Period(ldt, now);


PeriodFormatter formatter = new PeriodFormatterBuilder()
    .printZeroNever() // default setting so not really necessary
    .appendSeconds().appendSuffix(" seconds ago\n")
    .appendMinutes().appendSuffix(" minutes ago\n")
    .appendHours().appendSuffix(" hours ago\n")
    .appendDays().appendSuffix(" days ago\n")
    .appendWeeks().appendSuffix(" weeks ago\n")
    .appendMonths().appendSuffix(" months ago\n")
    .appendYears().appendSuffix(" years ago\n")
    .toFormatter();

String elapsed = formatter.print(p);
model.addAttribute("elapsed", elapsed);
System.out.println(elapsed);
```

Output:

```
32 seconds ago
37 minutes ago
20 hours ago
4 days ago
1 weeks ago
10 months ago
2 years ago
```

If you have higher expectations/requirements for formatting then you have to consider following details:

- localization (is English only enough?)
- plural rules (singular/plural etc.)
- list output versus relative times using the biggest unit only (Joda-Time supports list output via `PeriodFormat.wordBased()` but you have then to add the suffix " ago" yourself)
- full text widths versus abbreviations ("seconds" vs "secs" or "s")

Alternatives for formatting:

- writing your own formatting routine (only for one locale)
- [ocpsoft/PrettyTime](http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/) (using `java.util.Date`)
- my library [Time4J](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/PrettyTime.html)